# removing time from angular date function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have currently set up date formatting on my app..

Html

```
<span ng-bind="convertToDate(myDate) | date: 'medium'" id="dtText"></span>
```

Angular

```
$scope.myDate = new Date();
$scope.convertToDate = function (stringDate) {
var dateOut = new Date(stringDate);
dateOut.setDate(dateOut.getDate());
return dateOut;
};
```

I have the function working however it is displaying the time which i would like to remove. Just wondering what i would need to add to my function in order to prevent the time from displaying ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about just using

```
<span ng-bind="myDate | date: 'mediumDate'" id="dtText"></span>
```

No need to convert it.

The reason your `convertDate` function doesn't work is that `Date.setDate` only sets the date portion of the date value, leaving the time components intact. To reset the time components you would have to reset them individually something like

```
dateOut.setSeconds(0);
dateOut.setMinutes(0);
dateOut.setHours(0);
```

Comment: it does work, i'm trying to remove the time for the attribute and add the day of the week to it

Comment: the line `dateOut.setDate(dateOut.getDate());` doesn't actually do anything. Your function may convert a string value to a Date. Given that `myDate` is already a Date it doesn't do what I think you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

Specify format of date as argument

```
<span ng-bind="myDate | date: 'MMM d,y'" id="dtText"></span>
```

Comment: the `medium` format for the date filter actually uses `MMM d, y` as the format string.

Comment: I meant to say `medium` uses `MMM d,y` as the format for the date part.