# Date in Javascript and Java(Spring boot)

Tags: javascript, java, date

I've read many posts on this topic, still i have some questions

first i get an date input (28/09/2019) from html input tag, let's call it `aDate`

```
<input name="ExpireDate" ng-model="personalDetail.ExpireDate" type="date">
```

in Javascript

`console.log(aDate)` gives `Sat Sep 28 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)`

`console.log(aDate.toISOString())` gives `2019-09-27T14:00:00.000Z`

i know they are both correct as the first one is UTC+10 time and the second one is UTC+0 time

and then i pass `aDate` to a spring boot application, it shows `2019-09-27T14:00:00.000Z` if i parse it to `LocalDate`(which is supported by postgresql) it will lose `T14:00:00.000Z` part

then if i try to convert `LocalDate` `2019-09-27` in Java to `Date` in Javascript the date is now one day off.

my current solution is use `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate`, it worked but i really dont want to store that time info in database

is there a way to get rid of the time info in Javascript `Date`? or any other solutions to tackle this

another strange things is why i specified `type="date"` in html input tag, it still give me datetime data?

> UPDATE:
>
> `LocalDateTime` does not work

converting `2019-09-27T14:00:00.000Z` to `LocalDateTime` yields `2019-09-27T14:00`

but in Javascript `new Date('2019-09-27T14:00')` treats it as local time and yields

```
"Fri Sep 27 2019 14:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)"
"2019-09-27T04:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing time from angular date function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161753/removing-time-from-angular-date-function)

Comment: Why don't you send the value as a string, and accept it as a string? There's no need to use `Date` objects for this.

Comment: ECMAScript parses 2019-09-27 as UTC (an error when writing the spec IMHO). Just don't use the built–in parser, write your own functions or use a library. For someone in, say, Ottowa `new Date('2019-09-27').toLocaleString()` will produce a date for 26/09/2019.